# Increasing CPU usage on server side

Tags: python, client-server, cpu-usage

I've written a client-server program in python. I want my server to do a CPU intensive job, so I'm calculating the factorial of 200 for 20000 iterations for one single request from client(client sends the request in an infinite loop). It's CPU usage increases for sometime to 50% but then it decreases and returns empty string. However, when I'm just sending a string in an infinite loop and on the server-side it just prints the string, It's CPU usage increases drastically(above 80%), not able to figure out why is this so?

and also I want to do some more realistic job on server-side rather than just sending a string which can increase its CPU usage to close to 90% or more and at times I can also be able to do which doesn't increases its CPU usage and remains below the threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the topic, your goal seems to be to load the CPU that you have on your server and it is not directly related to python. Besides that it is hard to judge what you program is doing "wrong" without any code.

If your server uses Linux, [check out `stress` utility](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/stress-test-linux-unix-server-with-stress-ng/). It can do that for you.

If you server runs Windows, [this topic might be helpful](https://superuser.com/questions/396501/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-windows) in terms of stressing CPU.

If you need Pythonic solution, you can [refer to this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312756/how-can-i-simulate-cpu-and-memory-stress-in-python).

Comment: Yes, i want to load the server with some simple logic on server-side for each client request.

Comment: I added python bcoz i need answer which can be coded in python

Comment: Check out this repo. It seems to be exactly what you need - Python-based load generator. https://github.com/GaetanoCarlucci/CPULoadGenerator